# Double Jump causing problems?

Tags: c#, 2d, jumping

Here is my code. I have an empty Gameobject directly underneath the child with a small radius checking the ground every thing seems to be correctly covered, but for some reason the jumping mechanic is very finicky and broken feeling. Can you take a look a tell me what you see? Thank you for your time!

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float speed;
    public float height;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool grounded;

    private bool doubleJumped;

    // Update is called once per frame


    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if (grounded) 
        {
            doubleJumped = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetButton ("Horizontal")) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if( Input.GetButton("Left"))
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump") && grounded) 
        {
            //transform.Translate (Vector3.up * height * Time.deltaTime);
            Jump();
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && !doubleJumped && !grounded) 
        {
            Jump();
            doubleJumped = true;
        }

        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position,groundCheckRadius,whatIsGround);

    }

    void Jump()
    {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.up * height * Time.deltaTime);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> finicky and broken feeling

This should probably just be the issue because you're using `FixedUpdate()` instead of `Update()`, thus the groundcheck / jumpcheck, doesn't happen every frame, but every physics update, try changing that and it should be fixed.

Comment: Careful though. Moving time-based gameplay into the non-fixed time step of Update() can cause your game to play differently depending on the framerate (as soon as you have any non-linear behaviours). That's why physics and movement are normally handled in FixedUpdate().